JSF/Primefaces bean is not getting called when adding the new variables (Any type) or code. But the bean is called when the new variable is removed
I am having problem with JSF/Primefaces 6.1 with the bean. That bean has lot of methods includes map related and remote commands. After certain limit when i add new variable then the bean is not getting called and it has only about 3000 lines of code. Whereas if i remove the newly added variable then the bean is getting called. Not only variable. If i add another few lines of code also causing this issue. Another bean is there with 10k lines of code which is working fine. I have no clue what would be the cause?
Tried to increase the facelets buffer size from 64 kb to 256kb.
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>262144</param-value> <!-- 64KB -->
    </context-param>

Also increased the heap memory
Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -Xmn1365m

Tried by removing static, final key words and etc. If i add new variable or few line coding this error repeats.
